# Function to get position of an element relative to the top-most window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, position

This has probably been asked already, but I was not able to find any fix for what I am trying to do.

I am trying to find the magical combination of properties on the event object, along with scrolling and other offsets, to give me the **position of an element relative to the top-most window that may or may not exist within an iframe**. I am doing this in an attempt to fade in a small (absolutely positioned) image to the right of the element that is being moused over.

I am trying to get the position inside of a jQuery hover event. I have tried different combinations of the following properties:

```
$(element).position()
$(element).offset()
$(element).scrollTop()
$(element).scrollLeft();
$(document).scrollTop();
$(document).scrollLeft();
event.clientX
event.clientY
event.pageX
event.pageY
```

Does anyone have a function or equation that can give these numbers?

Comment: Are you looking for the position of the mouse, or the position of the top left corner of the element in which the mouse is hovering?

Comment: @jackwanders position of the element

Comment: can you show us the HTML you're working with?

Comment: @jackwanders not really, it's an enterprise intranet website (aka a huge mess). for the purposes of this question, imagine a span inside of a scrolling div inside of an iframe.

Comment: and you want the position of the span relative to what? the div or the iframe?

Comment: @jackwanders the top-most window - this is all in the question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to finagle some code that worked for this situation. Hope this helps someone in the future:

```
var timeoutID;
$(element).hover(function () {
    // cancel any pending fades
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);

    var offset = {
        left: 0,
        top: 0
    };

    if (top !== self) {
        offset = top.$('#divContainingIframes').offset();
    }

    var that = $(this);
    var elementPosition = that.position();

    var xCoord = offset.left + // distance between screen and iframe
        elementPosition.left + // distance between iframe and element
        that.width() + // width of the element
        5; // 5 pixel padding

    var yCoord = offset.top + // distance between screen and iframe
        elementPosition.top; // distance between iframe and element

    // call the show function with xCoord and yCoord
}, function () {
    // don't fade immediately, wait a half second
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
        // call some hide function
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way in modern browsers is `document.querySelector('.foo').getBoundingClientRect()` which `return`'s and `object` containing the properties `top` and `left`, which are the offsets of the element relative to the `viewport`.

The above method works in `IE >= 5` with a couple of easy hacks see http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/

Alternatively you can use the `jQuery.offset()` method, if you have `jQuery` on the page. Which will return the `elements` `offset` consistently cross browser.

Getting the `offset` of said element from an `<iframe>` can be a bit trickier depending on where your trying to get the position from i.e. is the script running on the same page as the `element` which might be in an `<iframe>`, or in the root page with the `element` in the `<iframe>`

If you are in the first case, you don't need to do anything as long as your element is being repositioned somewhere inside the `<iframe>` as you already have the correct offset.

if you are outside the `<iframe>` you need to take the `iframe.getBoundClientRect()` offsets into consideration, as the `element.getBoundingClientRect()` is relative to it's own `viewport` (the `<iframe>`)